# Calculation problem within opencv, Python

Tags: numpy, opencv

I was calculating Y from yCbCr for histogram equalization.

The kb value I want is "kb / (b + g + r)" => ratio of b to RGB in a pixel.

I thought it was a normal calculation, but errors continue to occur in this part.

It is as follows.

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
kb[y][x] = b[y][x] / (b[y][x] + g[y][x] + r[y][x])
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def transform(img) :
    height, width, color = img.shape
    result = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)

    b,g,r = cv2.split(img)

    kb = [[0.0] * width] * height
    kg = [[0.0] * width] * height
    kr = [[0.0] * width] * height
    yi = [[0.0] * width] * height
    yo = [[0.0] * width] * height

    list(b), list(g), list(r), list(kb), list(kg), list(kr), list(yi), list(yo)

    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            kb[y][x] = b[y][x] / (b[y][x] + g[y][x] + r[y][x])
            kg[y][x] = g[y][x] / (b[y][x] + g[y][x] + r[y][x])
            kr[y][x] = b[y][x] / (b[y][x] + g[y][x] + r[y][x])

    # ...
    return result
```

Comment: Pixels are saved in `unit8` type, adding some of them results in overflow. What about if you convert `dtype` of image like: `img = img.astype(dtype='int64')`?

Comment: Doing this has solved the problem!!!!
Thank you for simply solving the problem that I thought was complicated.